# Jquery.FileUpload with MVC 5 not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-file-upload

Using `MVC 5 , VS 2013 , jquery 2.13`

I am following [Max Pavlov](https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3) tutorial on github.

I have added all css and js files in my **bundleconfig.cs**. And they are rendered page. But in addition, as I am using tinyMCE, and other various jquery plugins, and they are also decalred in bundleconfig.cs, they also loaded in this page.

However, none of the **functionalities** of **FileUploader** is taking effect. All css's are applied and rendering correctly.

But **No javascript**. Files are adding first time, but after calling handler, as it's returnig `json` data, the data is direcly shown in the browser as `text/plain`.

In console its showing following messages :

[image]

In this case what should I do?

**My View Page :**

```
@using ClientDependency.Core.Mvc

@{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/UploadJS")
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js?cdv=1"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js?cdv=1"></script> 
        <div class=" row-6">
    <div class="container">
        <form id="fileupload" action="~/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
            <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                <div class="span7">
                    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                        <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Add files...</span>
                        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple onclick="alert('click');">
                    </span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                        <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Start upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                        <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Cancel upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                        <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                </div>
                <div class="span5">
                    <!-- The global progress bar -->
                    <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade">
                        <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
            <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
            <br>
            <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>

        <!-- modal-gallery is the modal dialog used for the image gallery -->
        <div id="modal-gallery" class="modal modal-gallery hide fade">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><div class="modal-image"></div></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-primary modal-next">
                    <span>Next</span>
                    <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-info modal-prev">
                    <i class="icon-arrow-left icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-success modal-play modal-slideshow" data-slideshow="5000">
                    <i class="icon-play icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Slideshow</span>
                </a>
                <a class="btn modal-download" target="_blank">
                    <i class="icon-download"></i>
                    <span>Download</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
        <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
            {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
            <tr class="template-upload fade">
                <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
                <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
                <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
                {% if (file.error) { %}
                <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
                {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
                <td>
                    <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
                </td>
                <td class="start">
                    {% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">
                        <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                        <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
                    </button>
                    {% } %}
                </td>
                {% } else { %}
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                {% } %}
                <td class="cancel">
                    {% if (!i) { %}
                    <button class="btn btn-warning">
                        <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                        <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
                    </button>
                    {% } %}
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% } %}
</script>
    <!-- The template to display files available for download -->
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
        {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-download fade">
            {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
            {% } else { %}
            <td class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            {% } %}
            <td class="delete">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                    <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% } %}
    </script>
</div>
```

**controller Page** is OK I think. So its not shown here.

**My BundleConfig.cs is like:** Only RegisterBundle() method is here.

```
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
        //            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
        //            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
        //          "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
        //          "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        //bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
        //          "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
        //          "~/Content/site.css"));


        //External Fancy Theme implemented by Tofael............................................

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/modernizr.custom.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryNavigation").Include(
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.responsivemenu.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/superfish.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/nav-small.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/mobile.menu.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryRevolutionSlider").Include(
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquerySlider").Include(
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.flexslider.text.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.flex-owl-slider-min.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.elastislide.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryEasyPieChart").Include(
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.easypiechart.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryImagehover").Include(
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery-hover-effect.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryColorbox").Include(
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryTooltip").Include(
                  "~/Theme/js/tooltip.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.tipsy.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.ui.totop.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/jquery.isotope.min.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/popover.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/imagebox.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryRevolutionSliderOwl").Include(
                  "~/Theme/js/owl.carousel.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryScript").Include(
                  "~/Theme/js/script.js",
                  "~/Theme/js/custom.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssfont").Include(
                  "~/Theme/css/font-awesome.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/style.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/carousel.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/colorbox.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/elements.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/rv.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/fdw-demo.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/flex-owl-slider.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/forms.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/rv.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/ie.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/imagebox.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/skeleton.css",
                  "~/Theme/css/superfish.css",
                  "~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.min.css",
                  "~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css",
                  "~/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.css"
                  ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssGridMvc").Include(
                  "~/Content/Gridmvc.css",
                  "~/Content/gridmvc.datepicker.css",
                  "~/Content/gridmvc.datepicker.min.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryGridMvc").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/UploadJS").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js",
                  "~/Content/FileUpload/tmpl.min.js",
                  "~/Content/FileUpload/canvas-to-blob.min.js",
                  "~/Content/FileUpload/load-image.min.js",
                  "~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js",
                  "~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js",
                  "~/Content/FileUpload/jquery.iframe-transport.js",
                  "~/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js",
                  "~/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ip.js",
                  "~/Content/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js",
                  "~/Content/FileUpload/locale.js",
                  "~/Content/FileUpload/main.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryTinymce").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js",
                  "~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js"));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
    }
```

Comment: Try http://www.dropzonejs.com/, it is very easy to use and customize.

Answer (score 2):

In your view, you are including the `~/bundles/UploadJS` bundle which includes `"~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"` AND separately including `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js?cdv=1` in your view.

Pick one or the other.

Also, Change

```
@{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/UploadJS")
}
```

to

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/UploadJS")
```

Otherwise it will not output the result

Comment: i picked `~/bundles/UploadJS`... but no change.

Answer (score 0):

From a cursory glance at your browser's dev console, it looks like the library's relying on blueimp's cross-browser (includes IE9) solution for handling file uploads.

The solution takes 3 javascript files, all of which seems included in the bundle called "~/bundles/UploadJS".

The files you need, per the example [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin), are:

```
<!-- Should be included with jquery.ui -->
<script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
```

Can you make sure you include that particular bundle **after** you declare jquery?

Comment: Re-reading your post, just in case it isn't clear, merely including a bundle in BundleConfig.cs does not include the scripts in your page.  You'd actually have to include them in the page, like such:
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/UploadJS")

Comment: may be `<script src="js/jquery.ui.min.js"></script>` is covering widget.js. I am not sure. Is it?  Sorry, I used that, but while posting question deleting commented lines, I have removed the line. Rest of two files are used correctly.

Comment: Just for giggles, can you include all three files manually without the use of bundles?  Your browser developer console seems to indicate that these files are having no effect extending jquery at all.

Comment: ok, but there are no files like <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>. where should I get it? I have downloaded the jaquery.UI now again. But there are no such file.

Comment: I have created a file `jquery.ui.widget.js` with this name from **code.google** and loaded three of them manually... still now same problem.

Comment: Reviewing your view file, can you please put @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/UploadJS") **AFTER** your jquery calls, as in, **AFTER**
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js?cdv=1"></script>